# mongodb change database timezone

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I use spring boot and mongodb. when i persist object in db it change to my local time zone .it is for my mongo TimezoneOffset that is -210 when i run this command on mongo:
`new Date().getTimezoneOffset() =>  -210`.  problem is start from production mongodb in another server that this value is `new Date().getTimezoneOffset() =>  0`!

**question** is how can I make `TimezoneOffset` in development like production MongoDB?

a java class that I persist is:

```
Class AuditDocument{

    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String creatorUsername;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createDate;
}
```

document in development MongoDB that createDate is -3:30 from current time:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f697ee483eede29e2c13a2d"),
    "creatorUsername" : "superadmin",
    "createDate" : ISODate("2020-09-22T04:34:44.798Z"),
}
```

Comment: `ISODate("2020-09-22T04:34:44.798Z")` means UTC time, so I don't see why your local time zone would be relevant. To **display** this time in your local time zone is usually in responsibility of your client application, not the server.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit mongo change it to -210 minute ago. my local time zone is +3:30. in default i hope development mongodb is ok and production must be change because for preview data, users want to see their local time. but in this case only unification of `TimezoneOffset` value is my problem.

Comment: `TimezoneOffset` is not a property of the MongoDB, it is defined in the client. Maybe set environment variable like `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.timezone=Europe/Zurich`

Comment: unfortunately this variable not in my local machine (windows) and mongodb (linux) environment. (linux command: printenv JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS =>  empty)

Comment: Well, then set it!

Answer (score 0):

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` gives you the timezone offset on the client system that is running mongo shell.

1. This has nothing to do with the timezone offset as used by the server. All times are stored in UTC in MongoDB.
2. This is completely separate from the timezone offset used by applications using MongoDB. Each programming language/environment has its own ways of setting the timezone offset.

You should research how to configure the timezone offset *in your application*.

Comment: is this ok that mongodb reduce 210 minutes from my local time for persist as utc time? if ok what is difference with another mongodb server that not similar action!?